# Is there a way to know which query SqlDataReader.NextResult has currently loaded?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatareader

I may refer to the original link from Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader

```
static void RetrieveMultipleResults(SqlConnection connection)
{
    using (connection)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
          "SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM dbo.Categories;" +
          "SELECT EmployeeID, LastName FROM dbo.Employees", connection);

        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.HasRows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name of the current SQL text");

            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", reader.GetName(0), reader.GetName(1));

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1));
            }

            reader.NextResult();
        }
    }
}
```

I've just inserted the code

```
Console.WriteLine("Name of the current SQL text")
```

in order to illustrate my question.

Is there a way to understand which of the either two is active (or loaded)?

```
SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM dbo.Categories;
```

or

```
SELECT EmployeeID, LastName FROM dbo.Employees
```

I've tried to "Add Watch" for the `reader` variable to see the changes, with no success.

Comment: What is there to understand? The reader will consecutively return the results from both queries (first categories, then employees). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't think there's anything built-in to handle this - if you need to know which result is currently loaded / being processed, you need to keep track of that on your own

Comment: The command has the Select object which has the Command Text.

Comment: No built in support, [dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper#multiple-results) has support for it, so you can look at at the source code and see how they do it with [GridReader](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/4fb1ea29d490d13251b0135658ecc337aeb60cdb/Dapper/SqlMapper.GridReader.Async.cs).

Comment: Thanks.   Purpose was to see more details during run time, logging, and debugging. just tyring to learn... Select_ object of _Command_ includes both statements, which is not helping, `"SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM dbo.Categories;SELECT EmployeeID, LastName FROM dbo.Employees` _CommandText_ of _readed_ is also the same. I did not know about _dapper_ _GridReader_.and just checked it, it's yet too much for me..  At least now it is good to know there  was no built-in support, :)